# Issue parsing multiple large video files quickly using mediainfodll library

Tags: c++, mediainfo

I have being using MediaInfoLib, to find duration of a media file, in my project without issue until I observed lately that when I try to parse multiple large video files ( MXF, MP4 and AVI formats) quickly in a loop, MediaInfo is unable to return all the information. My C++ project snippet is produced below. I have tried waiting till the `mediaInfoDll` object is ready. All the skipped video files work if they are individually parsed. Any clue? I found `ffprobe` application to be too slow and `vlc` library is not accurate for different media types. Thanks

```
bool getMediaInfo(CString filename, long& duration)
{
  MediaInfoDLL::MediaInfo movieInfo;
  if( movieInfo.Open(filename.GetString())) return false;   
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = 
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  while (true) {
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point present = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::seconds lapse = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(present - start);
        if (lapse >= std::chrono::seconds(3)) {
            movieInfo.Close();
            return false;
        }
        if (!movieInfo.IsReady()) continue;
        auto strDura = movieInfo.Get(MediaInfoDLL::Stream_General, 0, L"Duration"); //in msec
        duration = std::atol(CStringA(strDura.c_str()));
        movieInfo.Close();
        break;
    }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: How "unable to return all the information"? What is returned? How do you call multiple times MediaInfoLib?

Comment: @JérômeMartinez: I call that in a loop with the media file names in a vector container. Above snippet is the function that returns the duration of the media file.

Comment: Tested something similar in a loop (all in the loop, including the creation of the object) and duration is provided for all files, you need to edit your question with the exact (and smallest) code and also the result you have and don't like.

Comment: are you using multiple threads?

Comment: @JasonHarrison: Yes, I am using a separate thread only for parsing the media files.

Comment: I have a hunch that movieInfo.IsReady() is always true and that you only go through the while loop once. Is your function returning after a failed movieInfo.Open(...)?

Comment: I meant to ask if you were using multiple threads, one per media file. Not all libraries support threading.

Comment: @JasonHarrison: Single thread for parsing the media files.

Answer (score 0):

### Retry getMediaInfo(...)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if(getMediaInfo(filename, &duration))
    {
        return true;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}

return false;
```

##### How could I even dare to suggest such hackery?

Without more information and based on the symptoms, it seems this bug shows up indeterministically. If high load is causing MediaInfoLib to act up, then this will tell you that and also give you a workaround until the bug is found in MediaInfoLib. *[begin dry sly wit]* And if this doesn't work, we have successfully found another way to not make it work. Thus, narrowing the search.